# How to find out MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST location of an application

Tags: iis, iis-10

I am currently writing a security auditing script for IIS 10 in Powershell. I have never even remotely worked with IIS before. I am supposed to run commands like this:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/<website name>' -filter 'system.web/authentication/forms' -name 'protection'
```

Where can I find the website name ?
Thanks

Comment: Use `Get-Website` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-website?view=winserver2012-ps and `Get-WebApplication` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-webapplication?view=winserver2012-ps to iterate all sites/applications.

Answer (score 0):

As lex mentioned, we could use Get-Website or WebApplication to iterate all sites/applications.

If you just want to list the website name in the Powershell you could add below command.

```
 Get-WebSite | Format-List -Property Name
```

Result example:

[image]